# How to open Screen in Flutter when there is new data in database

Tags: flutter, dart

how to open other screen in Flutter when there is new data in database?

For example, if i insert data to database or rest-api from other device with specific user_id, how to open a screen/popup in the Flutter Application?

The Popup/Screen with detailed data should be open when the phone is locked, app isnt in foreground and usually when the app is in foreground.

How is that possible?
Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: send a notification?

Comment: This is data from database and if there is a new entry for the user then it should display this kind of screen!!!